# MSBuild fails due to invalid NuGet version on build server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild

I updated to VS2015 this week and along with that updated all NuGet packages in my website solution.

The site builds and run fine locally, however when doing my gated check in to my build server, I get the following when the build fails

[image: NuGet Error]

As you can see the packages are complaining about the NuGet version, but I'm unsure how to update the NuGet version on the build server.  I do have admin privileges to the server, but following the guild described at: http://blog.stangroome.com/2014/02/04/update-nuget-exe-version-used-by-team-build-2013-package-restore/ did not help.  For one, my folder was actually `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools` unlike the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools` described in the guide, but additionally I did not have a NuGet.exe within the folder.

I've done a full hard drive search of NuGet.exe, but could not locate it in any directories aside from the directories that are directly related to project source code (.nuget\NuGet.exe).

I have opened visual studio on the server and updated the NuGet version within "Extension and Updates" hoping that would fix the issue, unfortunately it did not.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue/errors presented in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the old-style, deprecated-since-NuGet 2.7-style "package restore" that's based on modifying your CSProj files to include references to a NuGet.targets file and a copy of NuGet.exe that gets put into a `.nuget` folder and ends up source controlled.

Basically, the version of nuget.exe that's on the build server is irrelevant right now -- your CSProj files are pointing to the file in your `.nuget` folder.

TFS 2013 and beyond has support for automatic package restore without using the NuGet.targets method. You can migrate off of it pretty easily: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Comment: does that mean there's nothing I can do if I'm on TFS 2012? (Aside from upgrade to 2013)

Comment: You can replace the NuGet.exe that's in source control (in the `.nuget` folder) with a more recent version.